# Suggestions for creating a windows XP-compatible browser?

Tags: c#, browser, .net-4.0, windows-xp, geckofx

For my internship, I need to create a customized browser that will host their web application and simulates it to be like a normal desktop app for the user.

I've already looked at a few possibilities to help me create a browser without having to write the engines myself and this resulted in creating small prototypes for Electron, CefSharp, and Geckofx, these last two were done in c# WinForms, where the default webbrowser control was replaced by a chromium engine and the firefox engine Gecko in the case of Geckofx).

These prototypes seemed to work perfectly with the site and looked very promising, however since making these demo's I got the requirement to support Windows XP as well. This requirement has complicated things because none of my already available options support Windows XP as of now.

Which brings me to my question, are there any packages like Cefsharp and Geckofx that are embedded into c# (via Visual Studio NuGet) and available to be used on Windows XP without breaking?

The webapp I'm creating this for fully supports internet explorer 11, Chrome version 50+, Firefox (don't know the first supported version) and Microsoft Edge.

It also seems to work with Opera version 36 (which is the last available version for XP) but I haven't found any kits that can help me create a browser-based on this.

**Edit 18-01-19:**
I was asked to also support Windows XP because the company I work for has a lot of customers that are hospitals. Apparently, they mostly use Windows XP to support the other programs they have installed on their desktops and as such I got the requirement to make my browser support XP as well.

It is also worth noting that the webapp I'm making this for, is currently used on a local environment and accessible via localhost in a browser. So the security concerns are not the main problem here as far as I'm aware of.

**Edit 22-01-2018:**
It seems that the current version of Geckofx (v45) is still able to work with Windows XP, it does, however, need the .Net framework 4.0 to work, so you'd have to downgrade to that version whilst developing. However, when I try this out I miss certain dependencies that make it impossible to use.

When reinstalling the NuGet version on .net framework 4.0 the references to Geckofx-core and geckofx-WinForms disappear, along with a few others that I haven't been able to pinpoint. Because of these lost dependencies, I'm unable to support XP with the Geckofx browser and I haven't found any good replacements for it.

The error I'm getting right now after "Xpcom.Intialize("Firefox"); is 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException: cannot find entry point with the name NS_Alloc in DLL xul' which causes the program being unable to start.

Comment: Did they explain you why exactly they want XP support for this project? You should have asked that. Support for Windows XP ended on 8 April 2014, it's an old and insecure OS which should not be used for any business purposes.

Comment: We have an open source product, Bloom, that uses c#/winforms/geckofx. Years ago it had an XP compatible version, which is still available at https://bloomlibrary.org/installers. You could install that and figure out what version of geckofx was in use.

Comment: I'd be looking at `geckofx`, it had support for `xp` more recently than `cef.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks I'll see if I can downgrade my demo to a previous version and try to get it to work with the current version of that webapplication.

Comment: @JohnHatton That seems promising I'll try to figure that out monday and will report back if it helped.